# Teaching a Python Ai Feelings Trouble

Tags: python, if-statement, text

So Im making an AI that basically records feelings that you have; like lets say it asked how you're doing and you say Super Good and it is not in "the ai's dictionary" then it will ask you if that is good neutral or bad. But im having trouble with the check program I made:

```
def pyaisetup():
    open("PyAiEmotions.txt", "r+")
    file = open("PyAiEmotions.txt", "r+")
    file.writelines('This project is all about teaching an ai about learning emotions\n')

    open("PyAiGoodEmotions.txt", "r+")
    file = open("PyAiGoodEmotions.txt", "r+")
    file.writelines('Good Emotions:\n')

    open("PyAiNeutralEmotions.txt", "r+")
    file = open("PyAiNeutralEmotions.txt", "r+")
    file.writelines('Neutral Emotions:\n')

    open("PyAiBadEmotions.txt", "r+")
    file = open("PyAiBadEmotions.txt", "r+")
    file.writelines('Bad Emotions:\n')




open("PyAiWriteCheck.txt", "r+")
file = open("PyAiWriteCheck.txt", "r+")
if (file.readlines() == '0'):
    print "ok"
elif (file.readlines() == '1'):
    print "wow"
```

So the program writes a 1 or a 0 depending on if the program has been run before but my program is just totally skipping the:

```
if (file.readlines() == '0'):
        print "ok"
    elif (file.readlines() == '1'):
        print "wow"
```

and it's annoying me. If you have any suggestions or any way to optimize this all replies will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `file.readlines()` always returns a list. Neither '0' nor '1' is a list, so none of these conditions is true.

Comment: ok? Then what? your basically saying "guess a number between 1-1000 but its not 2"

Comment: Why do you have those `if` statements? What are you attempting to accomplish with them, by printing "ok" or "wow"?

Comment: I am saying that `file.readlines()=='0'` is False and `file.readlines()=='1'` is False, too. You should use `file.readline()` instead. But if you call it twice, the first one will read the file content, and the second will read nothing (an empty line). Also, remember that `file.readline()` does not strip off the `"\n"`.

Comment: I just put that text there just for a place holder. the way that 1 and 0 work is there is a text file that has a default number of 0 placed inside of it and then the program runs and if it detects 0 aka if (file.readlines() == '0'): then  pyaisetup() would run and it would set the new value to 1 then when the program resets it will already see that the program has been run so it doesnt re-run the pyaisetup()

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate issues going on here. The first is the fact that you are using file.readlines() twice, and the second is that you have a conditional with two checks, but there are cases that will slip through.

If I have a file `abc.txt` with three lines, 0, 1, 2 then I get this behaviour

```
In [1]: file = open('abc.txt', 'r+')

In [2]: first_lines = file.readlines()

In [3]: first_lines
Out[3]: ['0\n', '1\n', '2']

In [4]: second_lines = file.readlines()

In [5]: second_lines
Out[5]: []
```

Rather, you should pull the data out once, into a separate variable and work with that.

```
In [1]: with open('abc.txt', 'r+') as f:
   ...:     lines = f.readlines()
   ...:

In [2]: lines
Out[2]: ['0\n', '1\n', '2']
```

Then you can run the checks on this (note, you might have to strip out the `\n` character for what you are doing.)

Secondly, your if/elif block will only return something if what it is checking is 0 or 1, not of it is, for example, 'foo'. You might want to put a final else to manage the default case.

```
foo = "foo"
if foo == 0:
    print('first')
elif foo == 1:
    print('second')
else:
    print('default')
```

Comment: `if 'foo' == 0` is always False, and so is `'foo' == 1`.

Comment: That's the point. It is an example designed to show why you might need the else.  I could adjust it to be a variable comparison, but the teaching point is the same. In OPs case, he compares a value against 0 and 1 and is surprised when nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The following fragment should work:

```
content = file.readline().strip()
if content == '0':
    print("ok")
elif content == '1':
    print("wow")
else:
    print("error")
```

However, you may use just the presence or absence of the file as an indication of whether the program was run before or not. Function `os.path.isfile("PyAiWriteCheck.txt")` checks if the file exists.

Finally, you can use exception handling:

```
try:
    open("PyAiWriteCheck.txt", "r")
    print("ok")
except:
    print("wow")
```